# What is wrong in my SQL Statement for select a table with foreignkeys?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, average

hi i have problems with my sql statements.

Here is my structure:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**first sql**: Here I have problems with Foreign Keys :(

```
Select Wohnung.Wohnungsnr, Objekt.Objektbezeichnung, 
       Hausmeister.Hausmeistername 
from Objekt 
group by Wohnung.Wohnungsnr
```

**second sql**: I need the average over all all Houses

```
select Objektnr, AVG(Miete)
from Mieter
group by Wohnungsnr
```

**third sql:**

```
select Wohnung.Wohnungsnr, Objekt.Objektbezeichnung, 
       Hausmeister.Hausmeistername, Mieter.Mietername 
from Wohnung 
group by Wohnungsnr
```

Comment: remove your image schema and post `CREATE TABLE` for each table. And provide sample of raw data and expected result set

Comment: Even though its fairly obvious what wrong, it would help if you specified the exact error you are getting from each query

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are not using the related tables where you should. You might want to read up on how to use the `join` keyword.

Comment: You basically have not done any reading on how to write queries. Hit the books. SO is not supposed to be a **source for free coding**

Comment: The first query only selections `from` one table, so you can't query for columns from three different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the tables

```
Select Wohnung.Wohnungsnr, Objekt.Objektbezeichnung, 
   Hausmeister.Hausmeistername 
from Objekt 
join Wohnung on Objekt.Objektnr=Wohnung.Objektnr
join Hausmeister on Objekt.Hnr=Hausmeister.Hnr
group by Wohnung.Wohnungsnr
```

The join could also be written as

```
join Wohnung using (Objektnr)
join Hausmeister using (Hnr)
```

NOTE - the parentheses are required